# If string in one file matches string in another, print line and next line

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm having trouble finishing off some python code I've been working on and will appreciate any suggestions. I have two files:

file1

```
>name1
>name3
>name4
```

file2

```
>name1 blah blah
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>name2 blah blah
cccccccaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>name3 blah blah
aaaaaattttttttttaaaaaaaaa
>name4 blah blah
aaaaaattttttttttggggggggg
>name5 blah blah
aaaggggcccctttttggggggggg
```

Each line of file1 contains a string also found in file2. For each line of file1, I would like to find the line it matches in file2, then print that line and the next line. This is my desired final result:

```
>name1 blah blah
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>name3 blah blah
aaaaaattttttttttaaaaaaaaa
>name4 blah blah
aaaaaattttttttttggggggggg
```

I so far have the following code:

```
nums=set()
    with open("file1.txt") as file1:
        for line in file1:
            nums.add(line.strip())

    with open("file2.txt") as file2, open("out.txt", "wt") 
    as outfile:
        for line in file2:
            if any(word in line for word in nums):
                outfile.write(line)
```

This code presently contains two issues:

- Any substring in file2 that matches a string in file1 is printed to outfile (using the example here, if >name3 is in the set nums, then lines starting with >name3 as well as >name31 and >name367 will be printed)
- I haven't figured out how to print both the line that contains the match and the next line (perhaps this can be done with islice?)

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Please clarify the specifications.  Are the names guaranteed to be in order in both files, or might your second file have the order `name1 \n name5 \n name4`?  If you want an exact name match, why did you test for containment (`in`) rather than an exact match?

Comment: Your problem with printing two consecutive lines is that you've surrendered control of `file2` to an iterator; this construct doesn't serve your needs.  You'll need to read this more directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **First issue:**

> Any substring in file2 that matches a string in file1 is printed to outfile (using the example here, if >name3 is in the set nums, then lines starting with >name3 as well as >name31 and >name367 will be printed)

This problem can be solved in 2 ways.

1. **Just add space.**

   If you're sure that after your "keyword" will be space, you can add *just add space*.

   **Example:**

   ```
   if any(word + " " in line for word in nums):
   ```
2. **Regular expression.**

   To solve this you can use regular expressions. You should `import re` and change:

   ```
   if any(word in line for word in nums):
   ```

   To:

   ```
   if any(re.match(f"^{word}\\b", line) for word in nums):
   ```

   **Explanation:** `^` means start of line, `\b` is word boundary. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/liOJWh/1) is the link to website for regex testing.

## **Second issue:**

> I haven't figured out how to print both the line that contains the match and the next line (perhaps this can be done with islice?)

You iterate over file using `for line in file2:` which read file line by line. If you want to print next line you can use few methods.

1. **Boolean flag.**

   To implement this you should declare boolean value before loop and set it to `False`. Inside loop you should  write line to `outfile` if this variable is `True` and change it back to `False`. You should set `True` to this variable inside your current condition.

   **Example:**

   ```
   read_next = False
   for line in file2:
       if read_next:
           outfile.write(line)
           read_next = False
      if any(re.match(f"^{word}\\b", line) for word in nums):
           outfile.write(line)
           read_next = True
   ```
2. **Change loop from `for` to `while`**.

   You can use `readline()` method ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)) to iterate over file manually.

   **Example:**

   ```
   line = file2.readline()
   while line:
       line = line.strip()
       if any(re.match(f"^{word}\\b", line) for word in nums):
           outfile.write(line)
           line = file2.readline()
           if line:
               outfile.write(line)
           else: # if the end of file reached
               outfile.write("\n") # delete it in case if you don't need this
               break
       line = f.readline()
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much @Olvin Roght, including for the detailed explanation. I ended up resolving issue one using the regular expression approach you suggested, and resolved issue two with the while loop. This got me what I wanted, just added in a new line character after the first line is printed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[]
# getting all the data from file and dividing them in two part and appending 
#them in a list
with open(r'C:\Users\user\RegForm.txt','r') as file:
    count =0 
    tmp=file.read().split('\n')
    for line in range(1,len(tmp),2):

        l.append([tmp[line-1],tmp[line]])


# getting all the value to search from file in a list
to_find=[]
with open(r'C:\Users\user\untitled0.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        to_find.append(line.strip('\n'))

res =[]
# searching for file if they exist or not

for i in to_find:
    for j in l:
        if i in j[0]:
            print(j[0],j[1],sep='\n')
            break

"""
output

>name1 blah blah
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>name3 blah blah
aaaaaattttttttttaaaaaaaaa
>name4 blah blah
aaaaaattttttttttggggggggg

"""
```

Comment: Thanks @prashant rana!